# use rsync with autossh

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keys

I'm trying to use rsync with autossh on my laptop, so it can also work when internet connection is less reliable, but it doesn't really do as I'd like it to do.

The starting point is that I have an alias to sync a directory to a remote server, using ssh and showing progress with `--info=progress2`.

Now I wanted to make this more resilient when on the go and internet connection might be rough for a moment. So I tried adding autossh, but it's having problems on many fronts. Though, just using autossh for a normal ssh connection isn't a problem.

my alias right now looks like this:

```
alias rsync23='rsync -e '\''ssh -F /home/localuser/.ssh/config'\'' -z --info=progress2 -ru ~/path/to/local/directory/ remoteuser@subdomain.domain.de:/path/to/remote/directory/'
```

with .profile containing the line `export AUTOSSH_PORT=1024` and ~/.ssh/config containing these lines:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 10
  ExitOnForwardFailure yes

Match user remoteuser, Host *.domain.de
  ProxyCommand autossh -N -T -q -M $AUTOSSH_PORT %h %p
  ForwardAgent yes
```

The error initially was (when not having `-F /home/localuser/.ssh/config` in there) that it would use my localuser to access the remote server and also not using the ssh key I have for the remoteuser, that ssh (and in general autossh) ask the password for to connect. Also just putting autossh into the command rsync is supposed to use for the connection results in errors that look like autossh simply isn't used. Adding `-l remoteuser -A -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` didn't do the trick, still the wrong user is being used, so I tried simply going through the .ssh/config file to force ssh to use the right user, yet no success.

I also already set bash to a more verbose output with `set -x`, the command being used does look correct:

```
+ rsync -e 'ssh -F /home/localuser/.ssh/config' -z --info=progress2 -ru /home/localuser/path/to/local/directory/ remoteuser@subdomain.domain.de:/path/to/remote/directory/
```

Anybody got experience with that and can help out?